# qt5 program with "-platform linuxfb" does not reset framebuffer when crashing

Tags: qt, alpine-linux, framebuffer, qt5

We have a qt5 program running under Alpine Linux v3.14 which uses a fragile legacy library which may cause the entire program to crash.  Alpine Linux switches to framebuffer mode during start up.  We compile the library from source but do not have the time to harden the code.

Our program runs in a Linux framebuffer device using `qtprogram -platform linuxfb` which works well, except that when the program crashes and returns to the shell, the framebuffer is not reset properly giving the incorrect impression that the program is still running but is non-responsive.

I would like to at least blank out the framebuffer and preferably switch back to the Linux console mode so we can see output from the invoking shell script.

How should I approach this?

Comment: Did you try writing a simple signal handler to do this?  That would be the obvious thing (assuming you don't care too much about cleaning up when `SIGKILL` is raised rather than one of the catchable ones).  It's probably a good case for a `longjmp` to the termination code.

Comment: I am not the qt5 programmer, just on the project.  I will forward your suggestion of a signal handler.